# How do I uninstall a velux blackout blind?

Tags: windows, blinds

(A [Velux](http://www.velux.co.uk) blind is a brand of skylight/roof-window in the UK that's apparently quite popular).

We have a couple of velux windows with blinds attached.  We'd like to swap them for the black-out blind variety, but having ordered the new ones, are at a bit of a loss for how to uninstall the current ones.

How to best do this?  Couldn't find any information on velux's site.

Comment: I agree with Ade's answer from May 29. I just couldn't seem to rotate it out however much force I used. I used a metal kitchen palette knife which has nice round blunt edges/point to not damage anything, and is very thin. My mounting brackets on the window are light grey, and the clips on the cassette are black. You can feel the sprung clip click away, and then the cassette drops out very easily, no need to push the clip on the other side, one side will do. HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an update to Peter Mounce's answer from: https://zebbakes.com/2011/06/21/how-to-uninstall-a-velux-black-out-blind/

The Mr McDonald method at the end worked for me in a couple of seconds, and **doesn't have the crazy screwdriver involvement**. 
The quote is:

> spoke with a very helpful chap at Velux (UK) and removed the blind quite easily. Method was this: 1) With the blind retracted fully, grasp the casing firmly at each end with your fingers at the back (between casing and glass) and thumbs on the front. 2) Now twist/rotate the case up and out (as if twisting case toward top of window frame) and listen for the ‘click’ of the catches releasing both sides. 3) When both catches released – blind should slide forward and out! Tried it and it worked a treat! Obviously no guarantee but was reassured by Velux that if the clips should break on attempting removal that they can supply a new set of brackets for re-installation.

Comment: To augment Nick Hawes response. Its fine for what it says.
It may be obvious to others but you have to remove the side sliders first then the blind unit just pops off using Nicks response.
I need to remove everything as the side cords had come loose.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for information and the best link I found was http://zebbakes.com/2011/06/21/how-to-uninstall-a-velux-black-out-blind/, which was both informative and amusing.

It says to take a flat-head screwdriver, wrap it in a cloth, and then insert it between blind and glass, then twist it in small increments until the blind pops out by brute force.

**It is possible to break the glass by using this method**.

Answer (score 1):

I have been  able to do it using my hands - they are not massive. Simply by swinging the velux round and using the same technique as above but with my hand and I little bit of brute force. It is off and no part broken. Whoopee!

Comment: Thank you Graeme. We have been trying on and off for a week or two with ours and your technique worked in about ten seconds. Open window, grab blind in middle and use to move window up and down until the blind comes out in your hands. Mine has left two plastic plaques on the window frame which I guess the blind was clicked onto. We didn't install it so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using your hands is the best option. I have just finished replacing seven old blinders with shiny new ones and I could remove them all without damage (not that I cared!) by simply pulling with my bare hands. It takes a while to understand that you must not pull towards you but slightly down

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent an hour struggling to remove mine,so thought I would share my technique in case it's of use to anyone else.

My window is quite narrow making removal especially difficult. I tried twisting and brute force as suggested, but made zero progress. The 'screwdriver in towel' method made me too worried that I'd put excessive strain on the glass and break it.

I managed to get mine off by tearing and folding cardboard into shims. Starting off with narrow strips, gently prying the frame away from the glass and shimming the frame up all along with progressively thicker cardboard I was finally able to get it to click off the mounting clip without damage to glass or blind.

I hope this helps someone, commiserations to anyone who's ended up on this page: wtf are velux playing at designing a blind with no good way to remove it!

Answer (score 0):

We have three velox windows and each had a blackout blind with a "Night Sky" finish.

1. Removed (and clean) side fittings.
2. Removed the slide spring ends (and clean).
3. Opened window and grasped blind cassette with both hands and gently opened / closed the window = Bingo ! In less than 20 seconds the cassette came away from the window fittings.
4. Cleaned the cassette.
5. Re-installing cassette into the left hand window.

Answer (score 0):

Unscrew the side strips and slide down the windows to remove from the cassette
If you look down the side of the cassette you will see the grey plastic mounting which the cassette clips onto.

There is a small piece of sprung plastic on the side of cassette which locks it in place.

If you carefully slide a thin blade between the cassette and the grey mounting (I used a butter knife because it is flat and about the right width) keeping the edge of the blade close the top of the window you can push the sprung plastic clip back and the cassette drops out easily - no force required.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Hawes' post above - Velux told me to get fingers between glass and blind, slightly off centre, and pull away from the glass. This was for the older type blind I had with the 2" (50mm) deep head fascia which overhangs the frame, so you cannot twist it (ie not the modern mitred narrow edge trim which sits within the frame). Be careful though, mine did not come away easily, no click as catches released; it took a hard pull and it suddenly shot off hitting me on the forehead. Not something to be done standing on a chair/steps as you'll fall.

Answer (score 0):

I really struggled removing my Velux blinds which were fitted in 2002. The front face overlapped the frame as has been mentioned elsewhere so twisting was impossible.

I thought about the flat bladed knife solution but decided to use a lightweight pin hammer, with a wedge shaped head, between the blind and the glass. I slid a piece of thin plywood between the hammer and glass to spread the load. It then levered out, relatively easily, but coming away suddenly so be careful!The brackets in the frame are different.

The left hand one has a hole in. The right hand one has a curved slot in, open at the bottom end. They are a push fit into 2 predrilled holes (each) in the frame. When fitting a genuine Replacement Velux blind one of the screw holes coincides with one of these holes so filled that using a bit of dowel, or wood filler would do. Hope the new blinds last another 18 years, but at least it's more obvious how they come off.

Answer (score 0):

Having removed the side-rails, my "cassette" (roller blind) was stuck. Armed with Nick Hawes answer I used a bit of brute force, holding both ends and rotating it axially away from the glass and upwards.  Applying substantial force it eventually came away, one end first after which the other end was easy.

Answer (score 0):

VELEX Blind DKL 33AV0X

This blind has a silver trim at the front that overlaps the frame and cannot be twisted.

I opened the window and then stood inside. I grabbed the blind with my fingers on the top of the blind and my thumbs below and my hands evenly spaced to that 1/3 of the length of the blind was on each side of my hands. I then pulled the blind sharply towards me. The blind came away from the window with a "crack". Inspection shows that there are no catches or releases and the only way to remove the blind is to pull it straight out as described.